# Punctuation symbols are spoken as words

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I have implemented the text to speech converter in my website using speech synthesis utterance in JavaScript.

```
var obj = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
```

This is working fine but all the punctuation are also read as an word.
For example (.) is read as dot.
Is there any way that I can overcome this?

Here is the complete code.

```
HTML:

      <div class="article-abstract">
<p>Enterprise service management is all about having all departments in the company define their service delivery processes around a common standard and use the same technology and tool set to deliver those services. This really is the USP of ESM where a company is able to take operational excellence from one department and apply it to achieve greater results in other departments too. This is becoming a trend of late because of the consumerisation of technology and business functions like sales, marketing, HR, facilities management, legal etc looking to deploy technology to deliver their services to their users. </p>
<p>The market size of IT service management itself stands anywhere between $5 bn and $6 bn. And that ESM applies to functions beyond the IT department, it is safe to assume the ESM market size to anywhere between $18 bn and $20 bn. ManageEngine, a division of Zoho Corp, has been a leader in the ITSM space over the last decade with more than 100,000 customers around the world. The flagship ServiceDesk Plus product is available both from the Cloud and as installable on-premises software and this is purpose built for IT service management. ManageEngine’s ITSM product suite also includes products for MSPs, customer support, asset management etc. </p>
  </div>

<button id="speakButton">Speak</button>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    var text= $('.article-abstract').text();
    var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    u.text = text;
    u.lang = 'en-US';

    $('#speakButton').click(function () {
                speak(text);
        });

    function speak(text, callback) {
           speechSynthesis.speak(u);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to provide more complete code to enable others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: please find the updated code

Comment: What browser do you use, what OS do you use? What voices are available in your system?

Comment: i use chrome and OS is windows 10

Comment: What voices are available in your system?

Comment: Microsoft David(English-US),Microsoft Zira(English-US)

Comment: What voices are available in chrome?